# Reverse cells in a table row in html

Tags: html, html-table, cell, reverse

I want to reverse the order of row cells in an HTML table with HTML attributes or CSS.

I've found 'reversed' attribute but it's only for HTML lists and reverses only list's counting.

```
[table]
    [row]
        [cell 1] [cell 2] [cell 3] [cell 4]
    [/row]
[/table]

...applying reversal....

[table]
    [row]
        [cell 4] [cell 3] [cell 2] [cell 1]
    [/row]
[/table]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abuse the `direction` property to get this effect:

```html
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>

<br>

<table style="direction:rtl">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment

Comment: This style (direction) will work well on all browsers ?

Comment: Probably but I am not sure